# '<number>D' causes CAST to error

Tags: sql-server

I'm finding this to be truly bizarre behaviour.

Here is my T-SQL:

```
declare @testText nvarchar(1000);
set @testText = '17D4,A,1';
select txt_value from fn_ParseText2Table (@testText , ',' )
```

where fn_ParseText2Table is a function that parses the text into a table where you can get the txt, int, and floating point values, if they work. 
The 17D4 is a product code that I'm trying to extract within a larger query, and all other 3817 records work fine.

```
select (
     select txt_value 
     from fn_ParseText2Table(t.primaryKeyValues , ',' ) as pk 
     where position = 1) as product_NBR 
from database.dbo.tablesToParse as t 
where t.tableName = 'ProductData'
```

I found the function [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str).

What I've found is that if the string starts with some numbers (I've tested anywhere from 1-4 ) followed by 'D', it fails with the 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' message.

All other combinations of text work. Lower case d is fine. C is fine, E, F, etc. So '17F5,A,1' is fine. Also 'asdf 17D5,A,1' is fine. '1D,A,1' is not fine.

I'm very confused. Is there a special escape character in T-SQL for 'D'?

**Update:** 
 I should clarify that the error occurs inside  fn_ParseText2Table()

**Update 2**
It's SQL server 10 - 64 bit, running on a windows 2008 server.

As well, I've tested this in a sql mgr query window:

```
declare @testText nvarchar(1000);
set @testText = '17D4';
select isnumeric( @testText )
```

The IsNumeric() call returns 1, which is why the fn_ParseText2Table() function tries to cast it to an in and it fails. I could add an extra check to that function to lower the text first and see if that's also numeric.

Comment: Oops, sorry to whomever was reformatting the sql so it was more readable. It looks like my edit overwrote it.

Comment: if lowercase D works find can't you just `lower()` the string?

Comment: one of the comments on the codeproject page says that this code has a problem determining whether the field is numeric, a fix is posted there as well, have you tried it?

Comment: This looks a typical string splitter but one of the slowest versions you can find. Take a look at this article which has a number of string splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Which locale are you using?

Comment: @Hogan - I'd rather not use lower() on the target string, since we don't have control over the source data, and although I'm pretty sure that the client's systems use upper case usually for their product keys, but I can't assume that's the case, so I wouldn't be sure the data would be correct after applying the toupper() later. Then again, I could maybe add an extra check to see if a lowered string is also numeric. (I'm about to add an update to my question.)

Comment: @KevinCook - good catch, I'll have a look and see if that helps, thanks.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` almost always answers a question nobody wants to ask - "can this string be cast to *any* of the numeric data types, I don't care which?"

Comment: @KevinCook -I found the comment you mentioned, and it looks like that solution will work and I can get this thing working, thanks very much.

Comment: @SeanLange - thanks very much for that link, I'll look into refactoring to a faster string splitter once I've got everything working. If it's slow for now, it doesn't affect anyone but a few of us behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it was related to floating-point literals but I was surprised it wouldn't cast to a numeric type. I guess it only works when float is the target type. You'll find the explanation here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic202581-8-1.aspx

This behavior doesn't match up with other SQL Server literals, ie, constants:

```
select 1d -- literal 1 with d treated as the column alias
select 1e -- literal 1.0 as a float
select cast('1d' as float), cast('1e' as float) -- neither of these will cast without an exponent value

select cast('1d0' as float), cast('1e0' as float) -- these work though
```